# Where can I get a list of devices that don't support Google services?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to decide if it's worth investing in doing Huawei specific dev for our app but I can't seem to find a list of devices that don't support Google Services. I want to figure out what percentage of our user base is using devices without play service. Is it based on OS version or device?

Comment: This is device based issue. Huawei mate 30 series and Huawei devices produced after 2020 will not have the Google Services.

Answer (score 3):

It is based on device.

Here is a link from Google listing Google Play supported devices; https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.html
Latest flagship series of Huawei like Mate 30 and P40 do not have Google services.

Since Huawei devices has a quite high market share, a fast ramp up on Mate 30 and P40 models would be expected. It is better to keep application adapted to those new devices considering the user experience. Huawei has their own ecosystem now and it would be a nice and simple start for such adaptation

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. There is no page for that (so far).

Right now no-GMS devices are:

- Mate 30 series
- P40 series
- Mate X